# How to draw cube without indices?OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios4, opengl-es-2.0, cube, gl-triangle-strip

I want to draw cube without indices and using VBO. I can't find anything in internet(tutorials,examples).
What I tried:

```
const GLfloat Vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, //Vertex 0
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //v1
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  //v2
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   //v3

    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //...
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,         
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,            
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,         
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,         
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,           
    -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
};


glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 24);
```

But it turns out that something strange, but not the cube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check in your glDrawPrimatives call,that you're using GL_QUADS as your draw mode. Anything else will give weird results.

You vertices are fine though. They're in the correct order and in the correct positions.

EDIT: Since you can't use quads, you will have to define each triangle individually, your first block will look like this:

```
-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, //v0
1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //v1
-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  //v2

-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  //v2
1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //v1
1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   //v3
```

I would highly suggest using indices though, if you keep the same vertex buffer as you defined, you can set up your indices like this:

```
byte indices[6 * 6];
int n = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4 * 6; i += 4)
{
   indices[n++] = i;
   indices[n++] = i + 1;
   indices[n++] = i + 2;

   indices[n++] = i + 2;
   indices[n++] = i + 1;
   indices[n++] = i + 3;
}
```

Comment: I can't use GL_QUADS, because in Opengl ES  GL_QUADS, GL_QUAD_STRIP & GL_POLYGON are not available.

Comment: Is there any way to render cube without indices?
I do not understand why indices needeed.

Comment: How to render with glDrawElements?  `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);`?

Comment: The first bit of code in my answer shows you how to define your vertices so that you don't need indices, just do that for all six of your faces, and draw with GL_TRIANGLES. If you want to learn about index buffers, take a look at this: http://playcontrol.net/ewing/jibberjabber/opengl_vertex_buffer_object.html